# Error al cargar la librería de SQLite en servidor linux/oracle " Failed to load native library: qlite"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, sqlite, wildfly

estoy afrontando un error de mi aplicación con las siguientes especificaciones

**Formato:** War

**Desplegado:** wildfly 21.0.2 final

**Servidor:** linux oracle

**creada:** Srping 2.6.1

**SQLite:**
org.xerial
sqlite-jdbc

mi problema es el al momento de crear una base de datos usando sqlite da el siguiente error

> 2022-06-30 16:31:06,779 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8) Failed to load native library:sqlite-3.36.0.3-fd7fd399-cf14-442f-a6f4-cc3fc549a232-libsqlitejdbc.so. osinfo: Linux/x86_64

> 2022-06-30 16:31:06,780 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/sqlite-3.36.0.3-fd7fd399-cf14-442f-a6f4-cc3fc549a232-libsqlitejdbc.so: /tmp/sqlite-3.36.0.3-fd7fd399-cf14-442f-a6f4-cc3fc549a232-libsqlitejdbc.so: failed to map segment from shared object

> 2022-06-30 16:31:06,788 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-8) Forwarding to error page from request [/backmovil/generabdsqliteforid/02] due to exception [/opt/bdsqlite/sqlite_mng02.db]: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/bdsqlite/sqlite_mng02.db

verifique que las carpetas `/opt/bdsqlite/`  y `/tmp/` exitieran y tuvieran los privilegios requeridos para creación , modificación , ejecución de archivos
TMP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

OPT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no creado una configuración especifica para sqlite simplemente uso la librería

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este inconveniente , he mirado foros y todos recomiendan los permisos de las carpetas pero en mi caso ya los tengo y no funciona?

o como puedo cambiar la ubicación de estos archivos desde el spring ?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré Solución en esta pagina, es una cuestión de permisos pero no lo convencionales , era algo de permiso de "noexec"

[Enalce](https://docs.opswat.com/mdcore/knowledge-base/how-do-i-check-if--noexec--flag-exists-on-a-linux-os-)

Comment: _Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia. Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia._